# How do I format a Txt file to CSV so that multi-line formulas would appear on the same line?

Tags: python

This is similar to what my dataset looks like.

```
mystring = """ID|Name1|Description|Name2|Type|Rate|Sign|B|C|P|U|Member|Formula
100|100|100 Cash|All|B|Rate|D|Y|Y||DATA|Total|
100|100|100 Cash|All|B|Rate|D|Y|Y||DATA|Total|
100|100|100 Cash|All|B|Rate|D|Y|Y||DATA|Total|
100|100|100 Cash|All|B|Rate|D|Y|Y||DATA|Total|
110|110|110 Expense|P|Average|D|Y|Y||DATA|Header|~BeginFormula~(expr(if rpt then 
if MemberIs([V]:[O]) or MemberIs([V]:[R]) or MemberIs([V]:[F]) then
if [cost] <> 0 or [cost] = -100 then 
[cost] = ([c] * [a]) + [a];
endif
endif
endif))~EndFormula~
100|100|100 Cash|All|B|Rate|D|Y|Y||DATA|Total|
100|100|100 Cash|All|B|Rate|D|Y|Y||DATA|Total|
100|100|100 Cash|All|B|Rate|D|Y|Y||DATA|Total|
100|100|100 Cash|All|B|Rate|D|Y|Y||DATA|Total|
800|sale|Dsale|bs|BL|Rate|C|Y|Y||DATA|Tax|~BeginFormula~(expr([sale] = 0))~EndFormula~
100|100|100 Cash|All|B|Rate|D|Y|Y||DATA|Total|
100|100|100 Cash|All|B|Rate|D|Y|Y||DATA|Total|"""
```

I've tried a few solutions, but the closest I can get is

```
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\text.txt', 
sep="|",error_bad_lines=False)
read_file.to_csv (r'C:\Users\TestOutput.csv', index=None)
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: `read_file['Formula'] = read_file['Formula'].str.replace('\n', ' ')` put this before `read_file.to_csv()`

Comment: When I run my original code it will send the text file to a CSV as intended but when it comes down to the formula "column" it will have the beginning of the formula in the correct row, column and cell. However, the rest of the formula that is located on a different line the text file will appear on separate rows depending on how long the formula is.